# "unexpected EOF on client connection" with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm using the sql abstraction layer of sqlalchemy with Flask, following the pattern indicated here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlalchemy/

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://' + DB_USER + ':' + DB_PASS + '@' + DB_HOST + ':' + DB_PORT + '/' + DB_NAME)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True,
                                  autoflush=True,
                                  bind=engine))
```

`

```
metadata = MetaData()

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)
```

with a scoped_session that gets removed with the teardown_request decorator before sending the response

```
@app.teardown_request
def shutdown_db_connexion(exception=None):
    db.session.remove()
```

Everything appears to work fine except I'm seeing a lot of the following lines in my postgres logs, which appears to indicate some problems with the db client connection.

```
"unexpected EOF on client connection"
"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer"
```

Any idea about how to debug this and fix whatever is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the rest of the server logs, it seems that this is a OS OOM issue. Marking this as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should call

`engine.dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case calling these code at the end of the program helped:

```py
session.close_all()
engine.dispose()
```

So the full sqlalchemy workflow looks like this:

```py
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(...))
...
engine = create_engine(...)
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
...
DBSession().query(...)
...
DBSession().query(...)
...
DBSession.close_all()
engine.dispose()
```